# Can't find tag property in cocos2D v3

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I updated the cocos library and have some inconsistency in API calls, the main problem I widely used tag approach to access the nodes, labels, etc. How to implement this behavior in the new the new cocos library version?

Example code:

```
CCLabelTTF *streetNameLabel = (CCLabelTTF *)[[self parentLayer] getChildByTag: StreetLabelTag];

Instance method '-getChildByTag:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Comment: the `ccSomething.tag` property has been deprecated in 3.x. Instead, use the 'name' property of CCNode !

Comment: @YvesLeBorg and how to implement getChildByTag now?

Comment: There is a CCNode+tag extension on github for cocos2d v3, but I chose not to use it - cruft forever in my code-base, yark. Instead, I bit the bullet and used the appropriate property. Did not take me long to modify my code.